# How to iterate a Pandas DataFrame and replace string if there is match of items from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My `df` data has two columns like this

```
thePerson  theText
"the abc" "this is about the abc"
"xyz" "this is about tyu"
"wxy" "this is about abc"
"wxy" "this is about WXY"
```

I want a result `df` as

```
thePerson  theText
"the abc" "this is about <b>the abc</b>"
"xyz" "this is about tyu"
"wxy" "this is about abc"
"wxy" "this is about <b>WXY</b>"
```

Notice if theText in the same row contains thePerson, it becomes bold in theText.

One of solution I unsuccessfully tried is this:

```
df['theText']=df['theText'].replace(df.thePerson,'<b>'+df.thePerson+'</b>', regex=True)
```

I wonder if I can do this using `lapply` or `map`

My python environment is set to version 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `re.sub` and `zip`

```
tt = df.theText.values.tolist()
tp = df.thePerson.str.strip('"').values.tolist()
df.assign(
    theText=[re.sub(r'({})'.format(p), r'<b>\1</b>', t, flags=re.I)
             for t, p in zip(tt, tp)]
)

  thePerson                       theText
0   the abc  this is about <b>the abc</b>
1       xyz             this is about tyu
2       wxy             this is about abc
3       wxy      this is about <b>WXY</b>
```

---

***copy/paste***
*you should be able to run this exact code and get the required result*

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''thePerson  theText
"the abc"  "this is about the abc"
"xyz"  "this is about tyu"
"wxy"  "this is about abc"
"wxy"  "this is about WXY"'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')

tt = df.theText.values.tolist()
tp = df.thePerson.str.strip('"').values.tolist()
df.assign(
    theText=[re.sub(r'({})'.format(p), r'<b>\1</b>', t, flags=re.I)
             for t, p in zip(tt, tp)]
)
```

---

*you should see this*

```
   thePerson                         theText
0  "the abc"  "this is about <b>the abc</b>"
1      "xyz"             "this is about tyu"
2      "wxy"             "this is about abc"
3      "wxy"      "this is about <b>WXY</b>"
```

Comment: Can you please test your code, not seeing ```<b>``` ```</b>``` when I run your code.

Comment: What you see is what was printed from running this code.  However, if you have the double quote character in your strings, that will mess it up.  I'll update the code with a simple fix.  When I ran this, I assumed the `"` were not intended parts of the string.  I just tested it with the `"` and it works.

Comment: thanks, going to try again. Just to confirm, this works on 2.7 version?

Comment: I'm on 3.6 but... yes it should.

Comment: it works, I had to do reassign ```df``` like ```df =df.assign(
    theText=[re.sub(r'({})'.format(p), r'<b>\1</b>', t, flags=re.I)
             for t, p in zip(tt, tp)]
)```

Comment: The reason I structured the answer this way was to avoid the `apply` as it tends to be slower, and in this case it is slower.  I also use `assign` because I don't like to propose a solution that overwrites a dataframe unless I have to.  There are many benefits to this but its a preference.  You could have also done `df['theText'] = [re.sub(r'({})'.format(p), r'<b>\1</b>', t, flags=re.I) for t, p in zip(tt, tp)]`

Comment: thanks, ```df['theText'] =``` is better. Sorry, I am python noob :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['theText'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'('+x.thePerson+')',
                                          r'<b>\1</b>', 
                                          x.theText, 
                                          flags=re.IGNORECASE), axis=1)
print (df)
  thePerson                       theText
0   the abc  this is about <b>the abc</b>
1       xyz             this is about tyu
2       wxy             this is about abc
3       wxy      this is about <b>WXY</b>
```

Comment: Hmmm, if need last value in uppercase `df['theText'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'({})'.format(x.thePerson), r'<b>\1</b>', x.theText, flags=re.I), axis=1)
`

Comment: I meant to show with last value in upper case that theText the match has to be case insensitive.

Comment: Thn need `re`, I try rewrite answer.